# Android Open GL Theoretical Question

Tags: android, opengl-es

This is very theoretical question about general knowledge.

First of all I dont have so far alot of understanding about things in Open GL so please forgive me.:

1. The best idea to load a 3D Model into android is using Waterfall .obj files yes?
2. I downloaded sample model for sketchup (some robot model with alot of parts) and the .obj file has size of 3mb. I  loaded it into vector of strings (almost 100k of lines) and the application is +15mb's heavier in ram usage!!!! So I am a bit concerned about this whole method.. and approach?
3. When I will load the model is there a simple way of rotating it and moving. Will it be like single object in open GL or do I need to multiply all thousands of verticals by matrix?
4. Is there anything else I should add to my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer all of your questions, but:

3) Yes. You can combine the Android framework's `onTouchEvent()` functionality to work with OpenGL. In OpenGL, you can rotate things very easily with simple `glRotate(angle)` calls (which will rotate everything for you), where the provided angle is variable based on your touch interaction.

EDIT::

2) Why are you loading it into Strings? I don't know models very well, but I parse many files. You should load into the smallest size variable you can. For instance an ArrayList of shorts, or something. I don't know your data, but that is the best way. Consider parsing in portions if you have memory issues.

Comment: but how about rotating single model? Can I keep all data once and make multiple copies of objects without copying whole verticles? Can I rotate only one element?

I think it all will need to be loaded into floats.. and maybe I will need to reduce the models. Actually I loaded it into strings just to see how much space does it take..

Comment: Strings are a Byte per character. So "1234.12345" = 10 Bytes, if it were a float, it would be 4 Bytes. I'm not sure what you mean. I'm looking right now at an OpenGL environment that consists of tons of points creating an object, and I can rotate the whole field together. You only allocate the vertices once, the environment is drawn in accordance to other things like perspective, translation, and rotation, all of which you can specify. You should research this first...

Comment: My development lifecycle is based on small research of most necessary possibilities before I actually start digging into topic and deciding that I will go with this way.. I was a bit scared that putting one model would eat my whole memory, that is why I asked these questions. I will research a bit more, simplify the models and come back:) So just if someone could answer about .obj idea is it good? Thanks!

Comment: To give you an idea. I render almost 1 Million float values between my position and color arrays and it performs no problem.

Comment: Also, your input file doesn't matter. You'll have to parse anything you use. You should add support for multiple filetypes (or model types) if you want to be proper.

Comment: RedLeader are you doing it on PC or mobile phone? as this might be important?

Comment: Android Tablet. On a PC you won't have the memory constriction I just specified.

Comment: How do you store your verticles ? Im thinking between a text file and a .xml file with integer arrays..